# factory girl - passing association data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am trying to change attributes which are set when saving associations

Factories:

```
Factory.define :course do |course|
 course.title "Course 1"
end

Factory.define :user do |user|
 user.name "Alex"
end
```

Execution

```
Factory(:course, :user => Factory(:user, name: 'Tim'))
```

The saved value will be 'Alex' not 'Tim'. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a similar factories. Your factory definition is missing `course.user` (maybe it was intentional), but on my system it doesn't matter. You may want to provide more data (gem versions, models, database migrations and so on) to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to add the association to your factory:

```
Factory.define :course do |course|
    course.title "Course 1"
    course.association :user
end
```

Then you should do it as a 2-step process:

```
user = Factory.create :user, :name => "Tim"
course = Factory.create :course, :user => user # or :user_id => user.id
```

And assuming your model associations and such are set up fine, this will work no problem.